# Uploading Folder with images to github

Tags: version-control, github, directory

As the title states I was uploading my project to github ( https://github.com/siddhartha-ramesh/FilmReview.git ), but I am stuck here. I cant upload a directory called img to github can anyone help me how to do that. I am not using any gui. Can I create a new folder in github.com just the way I can create new files?

This is what that is happening:

```
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/Desktop/Untitled Folder $ git remote add origin git@github.com:siddhartha-ramesh/FilmReview.git
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/Desktop/Untitled Folder $ git push origin master
The authenticity of host 'github.com (204.232.175.90)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? y
Please type 'yes' or 'no': yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,204.232.175.90' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/Desktop/Untitled Folder $ cd ~
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~ $ cd .ssh
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/.ssh $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "siddhartharamesh@gmail.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/siddhartha/.ssh/id_rsa): key
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in key.
Your public key has been saved in key.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
#key here
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/.ssh $ cd /home/siddharhta/.ssh
bash: cd: /home/siddharhta/.ssh: No such file or directory
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/.ssh $ cd /home/
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s /home $ cd *
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~ $ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~ $ cd ..
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s /home $ ls
siddhartha
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s /home $ cd siddhartha/
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~ $ cd .ssh
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/.ssh $ ls
key  key.pub  known_hosts
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/.ssh $ cat key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END RSA _________________
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/.ssh $ ls -a
.  ..  key  key.pub  known_hosts
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/.ssh $ cat key.pub
ssh-rsa 
#key here
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/.ssh $ cd ..
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~ $ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~ $ cd Desktop/
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/Desktop $ ls 
Aptana_Studio_3  C_C++  Codes  key  Untitled Folder  WS
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/Desktop $ cd Untitled\ Folder/
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/Desktop/Untitled Folder $ ls
film_review
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/Desktop/Untitled Folder $ git remote add origin git@github.com:siddhartha-ramesh/FilmReview.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/Desktop/Untitled Folder $ git push origin master
To git@github.com:siddhartha-ramesh/FilmReview.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:siddhartha-ramesh/FilmReview.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Do you mean adding it to your project? There's nothing magic about image files. Don't forget to add the directory and not just the files in it.

Comment: Can you tell us if the upload process returns some error? It's worth noting that an image _usually_ is a quite large file so that it takes some time to complete an upload.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your folder with your files (pictures in this case) in your local repo (cloned of your github repo), all you need to do to see that folder on GitHub is:

```
cd /path/to/that/folder
git add .
git commit "add folder with pictures"
git push
# or, if this is your first push:
git push -u origin master
```

In other words, you add all the files in that folder, and push them.

Instead of trying to add a remote, clone your GitHub repo first, add content in the local clone and push.
Don't use ssh first, use a simpler url based on https, and your login/password:

```
git clone https://siddhartha-ramesh@github.com/siddhartha-ramesh/FilmReview
cd FilmReview
git config user.name siddhartha-ramesh
git config user.email (your email address used on GitHub)
# add your files
git add .
git commit -m "Add folder"
git push -u origin master
# the next push can be simply 'git push'
```

Comment: I am really facing a lot of troubles, I did the same and nothing is getting uploaded

Comment: @SwaroopNagendra no problem, I have edited my answer with a step-by-step solution.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub's UI in this respect has not changed in all of these years. If you want to add directories via the GitHub UI, you have to do this:

1. Select Add file.
2. Don't pick upload file like you'd think. Instead, select "Create new file".
3. Up at the top where it says your project name, you should see "Name your file...". Instead of typing the name, type the directory name you're wanting to add and instead of hitting enter, type "/".
4. Now you need to either add a real file to that directory or just create a fake file name with fake contents. In my case, I just titled it "test.js" with "test" on line 1.
5. Now, you need to commit the file.
6. GitHub will create a directory and will upload your new file.
7. Now if you want, you can delete the test file and your new directory will remain.

Caveat: I'm not sure if you can create a nested directory two levels deep using the "/" trick or not.