# Uploading images on Github?

Tags: github

How could we upload images to a repository to a folder on Github? 
There was no such option 'upload' anywhere in the website.
Could anyone guide me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uploading Folder with images to github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873736/uploading-folder-with-images-to-github)

Comment: @user2686207 How do you upload any other file types on GitHub?

Comment: git add myfile.jpg && git commit -m "my image file" && git push origin master

Comment: we have a option to create a new file with a black screen, where I copied the code to github, but we don't have the option for uploadin g images

Comment: wbt11a : but the image was in my computer, I think it isn't possible to give directly myfile.png with no exact path

Answer (score 0):

You can add them just like any regular git commit. For example:

```
cd /path/to/directory/with/file
git add .
git commit "added folder with images"
git push
```